# ReactJS: Problem accessing this.context in a class based consumer component

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a problem to access this.context in a class based consumer component. I have the following situation:

AppContext.js:

```
import React from "react";
const ContactContext = React.createContext();  // Create our context     
export default ContactContext;
```

DataProvider.js:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import AppContext from "./AppContext";

export default class DataProvider extends React.Component {
    state = {
        contacts: {
            contact1: { 
                id: 1,
                firstName: 'Test User FN',
                lastName: 'Test User LN'
            }
        }
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <>
            <AppContext.Provider value={{contacts: this.state.contacts}}>
                {this.props.children}       
            </AppContext.Provider>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import DataProvider from "./DataProvider";
import Contact from './components/contact/contact.component';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <DataProvider>
            <Contact contactIndex={0}/>
          </DataProvider>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The consumer Contact.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AppContext from '../context/AppContext'

export default class Contact extends Component {
    static contextType = AppContext;
    
    componentDidMount () {
        console.log('My context is: ' + this.context);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="card"></div>
        );
    }
}
```

The console output is:
**My context is: undefined**

Thanks for any help

Regards
Dakir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only difference I see in the other answer's CodeSandbox is the import path is different.

`import AppContext from "./AppContext";`

vs:
`import AppContext from '../context/AppContext'`

Maybe OP has a filepath/import error?

p.s. If this is the error, [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html) is a lifesaver for avoiding these kind of things in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right to me, I tried to replicate it in a Sandbox to find out the error and somehow works like a charm.

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-https-emgoz?file=/src/App.js

Tried to spot the difference but I couldn't honestly.